# how to include an ofline browsable copy of html site in android app

Tags: android, html, resources, apk, offline

im trying to find a way to implement a simple android app that will contain an offline browsable  html site (a large collection of html, css and high res images around 350 mb) and capable of rendering this website offline.

I've tried to place the html files inside the assets folder and load the html using:
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

its working fine but the size of the apk is more 300 mb and it very slow.

so is there a way to do this without including the html files inside the apk file so that i won't end up with a 150 mb apk file?

regards

Comment: You can implement APK Expansions Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [APk Expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than
>   100MB. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the
>   application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for
>   high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets.
>   Previously, if your app exceeded 100MB, you had to host and download
>   the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting
>   and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is
>   often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more
>   pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large
>   expansion files that supplement your APK.

Comment: happy coding. (Y)